# How to implement database caching of data from third-party web service?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm trying to implement some functionality of caching data from third-party web service into the sql server database.

I have several methods like

1. `IProduct GetProductById(int productId)`,
2. `IEnumerable<IProduct> ListProductsAllByCategoryId(int categoryId)`,
3. `IEnumerable<IProduct> ListProductsPagedByCategoryId(int categoryId, int pageNumber, int itemsOnPage, out int totalRowCount)`,
4. etc.

So, I have an idea to code/hash method signature + parameters as a Key and serialize output as a Value and store this Key-Value-Pair in the database.

Then I'm planning just to get this items from the database by key.

**Question: Is it good idea and how to implement unique key for each combination of (method + parameters)?**

**Any other solution would be useful for me.**

Comment: makes no sense to me....

Comment: What about expiration? Are you going to hold the data indefinitely?

Comment: yep, Im going to use expiration datetime property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your asking, so I'm going to assume you want to just cache your objects...

The method I've used when I've cached is to have a static guid for each class type (keeps types unique), then I append "-" and the id of the object (which should be unique anyway).

As an alternative to the database have you considered using [memcached](http://memcached.org/)? - there are .Net versions around and they are very good, just make sure you understand where the right place and what to cache will be, to make sure it is applicable to your scenario.

Comment: Ah, maybe I understand what you are saying - you want to cache the particular output of a particular method given specific parameters. Your idea should work, but I've never seen anyone do this. Usually you cache your objects and call your method, your method then looks to see if you have these objects in cache, if not goes and gets them.

Comment: Yes, you are right. How to store objects in cache more correct?

Comment: Yes, so your method is managing the cache, so your client doesn't have to worry about where the data is coming from...